# How can I force stop a JavaScript image preloading sequence (preloader by Ariel Flesler)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-preloader

Say I have a button on a web page. Whenever that buttons is clicked, certain content (a whole list of image files that can go up to 5MB) is pre-loaded asynchronously and added to the web page when the loading is complete.

But it only makes sense to stop a pre-loading procedure if the button was clicked again before the first pre-loading procedure could finish, and then start the second. How can I achieve this forced stop?

By the way, I'm using [Ariel Flesler's jQuery based image preloader](http://flesler.blogspot.ro/2008/01/jquerypreload.html) .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably you will need to modify the plugin or create your own solution for preloading.

Comment: Modify the plug-in, yes. But how?

Comment: Best way is to create your own preload code, all you need is to create  image tag `$('<img/>').attr('src', image_url);` you can create tag for image with small delay using `setTimeout` and you can not call next `setTimeout` if button is clicked, you can keep flag which indicate click and unclick.

Comment: @jcubic Flesler's plug-in is quite safe and works like a charm, so I wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel and risk generating more problems than I'd solve. Do you have any suggestions as to how I could stop his preloader while in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's werid code there are 2 places where images are kept `img` variable and `$preload.cache` array.

you can add this

```
settings.control(function() {
    imgs = null;
    $preload.cache = [];
});
```

it can be after this lines

```
  var imgs = $(Array(settings.threshold+1).join('<img/>'))
         .load(handler).error(handler).bind('abort',handler).each(fetch);
```

and you can pass function to abort

```
var _abort = null;
$('<your button>').click(function() {
    if (_abort) {
        _abort();
    }
    $.preload( '#images img', {
            placeholder:'placeholder.jpg',
            notFound:'notfound.jpg'
            control: function(abort) {
                    _abort = abort;
            }
    });
});
```

It should work but I'm not sure if it will.